# Dependent cascading dropdowns in FormView with Model Binding

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, webforms, dependencies, model-binding

I use VB.NET and this question is regarding webforms. Here is a simple strongly typed formview -

```
<asp:FormView runat="server" ID="FV"
        ItemType="ExamDataModel.Student" DefaultMode="Insert"
        InsertItemPosition="FirstItem" InsertMethod="InsertItem"
        OnItemCommand="ItemCommand" RenderOuterTable="false">

        <InsertItemTemplate>
            <fieldset class="form-horizontal">
                <legend>Insert Student</legend>
                <asp:ValidationSummary runat="server" CssClass="alert alert-danger" />
                <asp:DynamicControl Mode="Insert"
                    DataField="CollegeID"
                    DataTypeName="ExamDataModel.College, ExamDataModel"
                    DataTextField="CollegeName"
                    DataValueField="CollegeID"
                    UIHint="ForeignKey" runat="server" />

                <asp:DynamicControl Mode="Insert"
                    DataField="CollegeID"
                    DataTypeName="ExamDataModel.Course, ExamDataModel"
                    DataTextField="CollegeName"
                    DataValueField="CollegeID"
                    UIHint="ForeignKey" runat="server" />                       

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="InsertButton" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" CssClass="btn btn-primary" />
                        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="CancelButton" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" CausesValidation="false" CssClass="btn btn-default" formnovalidate="formnovalidate" />
               </div>
           </div>
      </fieldset>
  </InsertItemTemplate>
```

I just want a cascading dependency for the dropdownlist (that is created by the DynamicControl) between ExamDataModel.College and ExamDataModel.Course.

As you can see I am using DynamicData FieldTemplate (UIHint="ForeignKey") to make sure that it displays a DropdownList. I did Google around and found these links, but I am unable to make them work in VB.NET.

[Cascading Field Templates](http://csharpbits.notaclue.net/2009/03/cascading-or-dependant-field-templates.html)

Is it possible to do this in code behind? I am unable to use the ModelBinding Control provider as I do not have the ID/Name of the control that will be rendered at runtime. Is there any Generic solution through FormView? Or should I stick with creating a normal Webform and manually deal with cascades?